# How to add a variable to a path in a .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file

bat files and I need some help. I am trying to make a scrip that acess a file. The isue I am running in to
C:\usesr\Hi\Desktop\AppData...
How will I make Hi auto find and fill what account you are on.
So if you were on Pat's account it will be C\user\Pat...
Is there a way to do this in .bat?
Any help will be greatly appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: `echo %USERPROFILE%` (and if that doesn't work for you, type `SET` and look through the list)

Comment: How will I use it in the code?

Comment: I don't know. You don't say what you want to do. Honestly, if you don't already know at least some batch programming, you should do yourself a favour and learn powershell instead. Or python, or ruby, or C# or Java or Visual Basic or anything except batch.

Comment: Thanks what I am trying to do is copy a folder and run a program

Comment: Thanks a lot I was over thinking it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use environment variables.

You could replace `C:\Users\Hi` in your paths with `%USERPROFILE%`

[Here's the list](http://www.askvg.com/list-of-environment-variables-in-windows-xp-vista-and-7/) of some basic ones you can use in your BAT/CMD scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot I was over thinking it :)